# (64 bit windows) timestamp error when trying to run MySQL database and set password

Tags: mysql, wamp

I am very new to servers in general and even cmd prompt. Anyways I downloaded MySQL and I am watching this video to set up MySQL at 8:21 in the video is my problem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4xXzTIcnDE. When I type in `-intmysql -u root -p` i get a warning like this.

> [WARNING] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEAULT value is deprecated

I found a few other post that i had to add some timestamp setting to a file. I am running 64 bit so none of these worked. Any ideas on how i can get past this timestamp issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's an error. That's just a warning. You could "turn off" that warning with a startup option (the message lines following the warning at startup tell the setting that needs to be changed...

---

Those nonstandard behaviors remain the default for TIMESTAMP but as of MySQL 5.6.6 are deprecated and this warning appears at startup:

```
[Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated.
Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see
documentation for more details).
```

As indicated by the warning, to turn off the nonstandard behaviors, enable the new explicit_defaults_for_timestamp system variable at server startup. With this variable enabled, the server handles TIMESTAMP as follows instead:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html

The options file is typically named `my.cnf` file, but on Windows, it may be named `my.ini`. (So, first, you need to know where the options file is for your installation, and then modify it,

Under the [mysql] section, add `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp`

```
[mysql]
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
```

That change will become effective the next time MySQL server is started.

If you are loading scripts for tables from older versions of MySQL, those scripts may be dependent on the older, deprecated behavior.